# NServiceBus Starts, Runs Briefly, Then Crashes

Tags: azure, nservicebus, event-viewer

I have a Windows service running on an Azure VM that uses NServiceBus. When I start the service it does start, runs for a minute or so then stops. The only error log I can find regarding it is in the Event Viewer.

```
Application: NServiceBus.Host.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue+MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS, IntPtr)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(System.Object, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType)
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(NServiceBus.TransportMessage, NServiceBus.Unicast.SendOptions)

Exception Info: System.Exception
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.ThrowFailedToSendException(NServiceBus.Address, System.Exception)
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(NServiceBus.TransportMessage, NServiceBus.Unicast.SendOptions)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.SubscriptionManager.SendSubscribeMessageWithRetries(NServiceBus.Address, NServiceBus.TransportMessage, System.String, Int32)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.SubscriptionManager+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Subscribe>b__0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I was reading older posts potentially about this same issue and people were saying that NServiceBus may be trying to log an error but the logger itself fails causing this issue. Has anyone seen this before or have any insight regarding it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the assistance of co-workers we discovered the issue. There was a message queue variable that was not populated and NServiceBus had an incompatible message queue name format which was causing the error.